# Keep posting number on line with for statements PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I am looking for something that shows a number on each line, rather than just all the numbers after the page has loaded.
the code for instance is:

```
for($a=0;$a<=10;$a++){
echo $a;
echo '<br>';
}
```

The output would of course be:
1
2
all the way to 10 after the page would load,
but I want it to show,
1
then 2, without the browser just loading everything.

I want a pause and to watch the numbers increase.

Comment: I think it would be better for you to use javascript for that kind of operation

Comment: not a server side task even with flush() you may not see output till full page load.

Comment: Agreeing with @user482594, this is something that can only reliably be done on the client side, most likely with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can force php to flush it's output with [flush()](http://www.php.net/flush).  Of course, if [PHP's output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) is enabled, this will only flush it into the output buffer.

Once PHP flushes, it's not guaranteed to go directly to the browser, PHP flushes to the web server, which sends it on to the browser depending on the web server's own configuration.

However, as far as PHP is concerned, the following will work (at least on the command line, or on your webserver, if it's configured right):

**demo.php**

```
<?php
ob_end_flush(); // make sure output buffering is off
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    echo "{$i}\n"; 
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

From the command line:

```
$ php demo.php
```

should display 1... 2 ... 3 ... with a one second delay between.

EDIT: One more thing I thought of.  Even if the web server does "stream" your output as you flush from PHP, if your output is in the middle of other markup, the users' browsers may not render anything until the entire response is received.

That said, if you're doing something basic, I've used the above strategy to output status for long-running utility scripts.  In those cases, I probably didn't even include  tags in my output, but it worked like you want it to (at least on the servers I was dealing with at the time).

This approach might be good enough for internal tools, but I'd never rely on this technique for anything end-users might ever see.

Comment: there are so many reasons in there that it may not work, rendering it basically useless (just saying is all) :-)

Comment: Did I miss any major reasons in my explanation?  Every time I've seen it not work is because there's something in between PHP and the client that does it's own buffering.  And in my experience, it actually will work in most mod_php setups (though I can't say I've tried it in a few years).

Comment: Also: If Dagon didn't downvote this answer, I'd like whomever did to speak up and say why.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a php script which will accomplish this.  It isn't really a PHP script, but rather a page that accomplishes the same with javascript.  Which gives you much more control with what happens on the clients browser.  With output buffering and everything else, there's no way to guarantee the browser will render it as you want to just controlling the output with PHP.

```
<?php ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        The Counting Page
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                var oldbody;

                function countTo(a,b)
                {
                    if(oldbody == null)
                    {
                        oldbody = document.body.innerHTML;
                        document.body.innerHTML = '';
                    }

                    if(a <= b)
                    {
                        elem = document.createElement("div");
                        elem.innerHTML = a;
                        document.body.appendChild(elem);
                        a++;
                        setTimeout('countTo(' + a + ',' + b + ')',1000);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.body.innerHTML = oldbody;
                    }
                }
        </script>
    <head>
    <body onload="countTo(1,10)">
        Here is the body text.
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not PHP, it's JavaScript.

Comment: Point is, you can't reliably do something like this in PHP.  PHP only controls what happens on the server, you can't get this level of detail on the client with PHP.  You can kind of simulate it a little bit, with flushing the buffer, but it's not a reliable method.